# How to see usr folder in mac when selecting files to open?

Tags: xcode, macos, finder

I need to open files in Xcode in the /usr but its invisible. 
I already tried

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES.
```

and restarted my finder but that didn't seem to work.

What should I do?

Answer (score 4):

In the open file dialog box, you can hit Command-Shift-G and enter `/usr` in the Go To sheet.

Comment: Or you can just start typing `/usr` and the Go To sheet will show up automatically.